# OCaml Trace: what is the star?

Tags: debugging, ocaml

When functions are traced using `#trace` in OCaml, the output may include something like this:

```
subRec --> <fun>
subRec* <-- "_1"
subRec* --> <fun>
subRec** <-- Var "_1"
```

What do the stars/splats mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is used to mark the result of partial applications to a currified
function. `let f x y = ...` is equivalent to `let f x = fun y -> ...`:
applying the `x` parameter returns a new function that, in turn, takes
an `y` parameter to compute. The first function will be traced as `f`,
and the second (returned by, say, `f 1`) marked `f*`.

```
# let f x y = x + y;;
# #trace f;;
# f 1 2;;
f <-- 1
f --> <fun>
f* <-- 2
f* --> 3
- : int = 3
# let g = f 1;;
f <-- 1
f --> <fun>
val g : int -> int = <fun>
# g 2;;
f* <-- 2
f* --> 3
- : int = 3
```